# Q&A site for Travel

Tags: support, area-51, site-proposal

Is it possible to set up a stackexchange site for travel inquiries, tips, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's already a [**Travel**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6591/travel) proposal on Area 51 in the commitment phase (there's an explanation of the phases in the [faq](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq))